# jquery make CSS background-image Property fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I would like my background-image Property fadeOut after 3 seconds possible?

i could just make dissapear but not fadeOut

```
$("input").css('background-image', 'none');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use css `transition` instead:

```
input {
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't immediately appear to work. Perhaps you could add an example with Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) to show exactly what you mean.

Comment: And apparently, [it isn't supposed to work](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties). Neither `background` nor `background-image` isn't an animatable property. You could do this with `background-color`, but not an image.

Comment: what I am trying to do is make the image in the input do a fadeOut: http://jsfiddle.net/930yrzqa/